# "Compiling" content with short tags to var, without eval()

Tags: php, eval, php-shorttags

To start off, let me clear the air by saying we **are** aware of the dis/advantages to using short tag syntax in PHP. That is not what this question is about.

Is there a way to "include" a file containing short tag code, into a variable, and have PHP actually parse the code?

`include`/`require` obviously do not provide the data in a workable form, and output buffering does not parse the short tag code because it happens at runtime.

Using `eval()` is simply not an option.

Suggestions?

Comment: "...output buffering does not parse the short tag code because it happens at runtime." ... What?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
ob_start();
$ini_sot = ini_get('short_open_tag');
ini_set('short_open_tag', 1);
include('file_with_short_tags.php');
ini_set('short_open_tag', $ini_sot);
$variable = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();
```

I'm not sure what you meant in your question about how output buffering was not suitable, but I have used it anyway.  I'm assuming your issue is that short_open_tags is not enabled on your platform, and maybe you just have to enable it temporarily in your code.

Comment: That's a great answer but I think PHP just changed the ability to change short_tags on the fly like that, see http://us2.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.short-open-tag. In >4<5.3 it worked but >=5.3 it has to be php.ini, .htaccess or httpd.conf, etc. (http://us2.php.net/manual/en/configuration.changes.modes.php)

Comment: You are exactly right. Before I got far enough to check, another source told me it was most definitely a difference between compile time vs runtime. Thank you!